# Shrinkable homogeneous compact and connected $T_2$-space

Tags: gn.general-topology, continuum-theory

A topological space $(X,\tau)$ is said to be *homogeneous* if for any $x,y\in X$ there is a homeomorphism $\varphi:X\to X$ such that $\varphi(x) = y$. Moreover, we say that $(X,\tau)$ is *shrinkable* if there is $S\subseteq X$ with $S\neq X$ and a homeomorphism $\psi: X\to S$ where $S$ is endowed with the subspace topology.

The real interval $[0,1]$ is shrinkable (it is homeomorphic to $[0,1/2]$), but not homogeneous. $S^1$ is homogeneous, but not shrinkable.

Is there an example of a shrinkable, homogeneous, connected, and compact $T_2$-space?

Comment: Just a remark: such a space can't have a open subset homeomorphic to $\mathbf{R}^n$. This would mean by homogeneity that it is a topological $n$-manifold. However compact connected topological manifold can't be homeomorphic to a proper subsbspace by Poincare-Lefschetz Duality (see Bredon corollary 8.4).

Comment: The product $S^\mathbf{N}$, where $S$ is the circle.

Comment: After @YCor, now we can ask about finite-dimensional shrinkable homogeneous Hausdorff continua, if there is any.

Comment: @WlodAA The [pseudoarc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-arc) makes the job.

Comment: $[0,1]^\Bbb N$ also works, since it is (perhaps surprisingly) homogeneous

Comment: Can anyone - maybe @YCor, the first with an example - put an answer to this thread so we can close it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While browsing the continuum-theory tag I noticed that this question was never answered, so I'm adding a CW answer just to remove it from the unanswered list.

As pointed out in the comments both the countable products of copies of $S^1$ (or any other homogeneous continuum) or of $[0,1]$ work. The pseudoarc does too for a finite dimensional example.